# Jenkins Blue Ocean retry a time-limited step up to n times

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

There is a step which execution time could very fast(microseconds) or very slow(hours).

Therefore, kill this step if it's undone after 1 secound and retry up to 10 times.

I already tried but didn't work, 1 and 2 will run just once.

[image]

Jenkinsfile:

```
retry(count: 10) {
  timeout(time: 1, unit: 'SECONDS') {
    sleep(time: 5, unit: 'SECONDS')
  }
}

retry(count: 10) {
  catchError() {
    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'SECONDS') {
      sleep(time: 5, unit: 'SECONDS')
    }
  }
}
```

---

How to design a step to achieve the purpose: retry a time-limited step up to n times until it succeeded? It's able to do this just using blue ocean steps?

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution is correct.

```
retry(...) {
   timeout(...) {
      // Your time-limited step here
   }
}
```

Mind you, it's going to also retry if your step fails for other reasons.

Comment: Is it work now? If yes, I think it was a bug and now has been fixed.

Comment: I have code which puts the retry inside the timeout, works fine. I don't have a need to wrap a timeout with a retry.